# Usando a Função Array_map

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar a função `array_map` para aplicar uma função para todos os índices de um `array` depois de executa o código ele trás esse `array`

```
array (size=13)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'a' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'b' (length=25)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'c' (length=20)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => string 'd' (length=19)
```

o que eu quero e que todos os valores de cada índice fique maiúscula usei assim

```
array_map('strtoupper', $Results);
```

depois de executar ele da erro pois preciso informa o índice dessa forma

```
array_map('strtoupper', $Results[0]);
```

ai ele funciona mais aplica a função somente no índice 0 ficando dessa forma

```
array (size=13)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'A' (length=20)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'b' (length=25)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'c' (length=20)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'd' (length=19)
```

mais quero que aplique em todos os índices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa chamar duas vezes o `array_map`, uma que vai iterar sobre os `arrays` e o outro que vai chamar a função para `strtoupper`, exemplo:

```
<?php

$array = array (
        array('name' => 'a'),
        array('name' => 'b'),
        array('name' => 'c'),
        array('name' => 'd'),
    );

$result = array_map(function($a){ return array_map('strtoupper', $a); }, $array);

print_r($result);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => A
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => B
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => C
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => D
        )    
)
```

[Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/lWTpGC)

Comment: Ou https://ideone.com/L0EyuV

Comment: também @bfavaretto